# I am getting this xpath error in eclipse , i think xpath is correct(1 of 1) but why am getting error

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

```html
<div class="u-grid">
<div class="u-truncate ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" ng-class="" ng-style="" tooltip="" tooltip-truncated="" ng-bind="$ctrl.parent.getProperty($ctrl.field, $ctrl.record)" xpath="1">24" Combination refrigerator w/ ice maker reversible door swing, Black</div>
</div>
```

xpath:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'24" Combination refrigerator w/ ice maker reversib')]")).click();

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the " after 24 because it is handle like a quotation mark.
Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'24\" Combination refrigerator w/ ice maker reversib')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you trapzerapzerix problem solved...!!!